# C library to watermark videos

Tags: c, video, watermark

Can anyone recommend a good library I could use on Linux to watermark videos? I want to overlay a watermark at several different positions in my videos, fade them in randomly and with different colors and opacity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried [ffmpeg](http://www.ffmpeg.org)? That's a very good tool for video related stuff. Also for watermarking you can try this [link](http://goinggnu.wordpress.com/2007/05/07/watermark-videos-with-ffmpeg/).

Comment: Thanks Mahmudul, I had a look at ffmpeg, but they changed things around and the vhook module is deprecated. :-/

Comment: @Frank Vilea - ok then you can have a look at this [stackoverflow post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1559691/ffmpeg-watermark-without-vhook). You can also look at [this](http://www.techenigma.com/2010/05/ffmpeg-watermark-video-without-vhook-solution/) .Hope this helps :)