# Personalized Video / Facebook App - What is the best approach?

Tags: facebook, html, flash, facebook-graph-api, html5-video

I want to build a facebook app featuring a personalized video which imports content assets from the user's facebook profile and their extended social graph and integrates these assets within the timeline. I am thinking of using Flash however a key stipulation is that the app works on mobile - and so I would need to use HTML5. My question is: Can I use Flash to build the application and then compile the app as HTML5 - or is there an alternative solution in the form of a HTML5 video toolkit with a programming layer that would allow me to build a web app / access the Facebook API?

Comment: Maybe this can be of help: http://www.techopedia.com/2/28138/development/web-development/moving-from-flash-to-html5

Answer (score 0):

I have done this a few times over the years and yes flash was the easiest however there are a few options which you have available to you that I know of which will be purely HTML5 based, personally I'd stay away from flash here as it will end up just getting int he way:

1- The cleanest method is to use a video compositing tool on the server side which can be programmed to accept variables. Personally I have only ever done this using ffmpeg however there a couple of alternatives which are out there. 
The basic process would be to grab the media from FB then to composite them at certain point on top/below/around a base video which is sitting on the server using a shell script which you then pass the media assets to as variables. There are so many options as to how you might want this to be done, probably best id to have a look at some of these examples:

http://broadcasterproject.wordpress.com/2010/05/18/how-to-layerremix-videos-with-free-command-line-tools/

http://graphcomp.com/ffmpeg/

[ffmpeg watermark without vhook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1559691/ffmpeg-watermark-without-vhook)

*note that last time I did this I used vhooks and custom filters, vhooks are now deprecated*

This method will mean a reasonably heavy server load if your app is popular but it's probably the most robust across devices etc.

2- Use [Popcorn.js](http://popcornjs.org/demos), and let the processing be done on the client side. you could hard code it using css/js/html but popcorn is pretty stable although I havent seen how it runs on devices but in theory it should work (all standardized technologies). Basically the process would be to use javascript to fire the display of images overlayed on the video base file at preset cue points. Popcorn has all of the methods and means for you to do this already.

Hope this helps a bit. Good luck, sounds fun.

Answer (score 0):

we realised some interactive video apps and one recent project was quite like your question describes.

We used adobe flash to track the motion - and published the project via create.js. You could have an image sequence from within create.js or put a video in a layer behind. This video would then control the player head time of the create.js motion tracked sequence via jquery.

worked fine - here a link to a testsetup with an image sequence.
Video Integration would be the next step.

http://www.jungeroemer.net/projekte/testpersvid/elftest01.html

(German text, sorry but it's nothing important to read there.
Just click the images and go for it)

you can download the sources from the link, if you need i can also upload the flash file to show you the motion tracking.